# Operator overloading with class template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am working on a heavily templated Mathematical Vector class. Its dimension and the type of components are all templated like this.

```
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

namespace Math
{   
    template <size_t D, typename T = double>
    class Vector
    {
        //
        // Template Assertions
        //
        static_assert(D > 0, "Dimension of an Vector must be bigger than 0");
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Component Type of Vector must be Arithmetic");

        //
        // Template Typedefs
        //
        template <typename... > struct typelist;

        //
        // Private Variables
        //

        std::array<T, D> _components;

        Vector(std::array<T, D> components) : _components(components), dimension(D)
        {
            static_assert(components.size() == D, "Component Count must match Dimension");
        }

    public:
        //
        // Public Variables
        //

        const size_t dimension;

        //
        // Constructors
        //

        template <typename ...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<typelist<Vector>, typelist<std::decay_t<Args>...>>::value>>
        Vector(Args&&... args) : _components{ T(args)... }, dimension(D)
        {
            static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == D, "Component Count must match Dimension");
        }

        Vector(const Vector &t) : _components(t._components), dimension(t.dimension)
        {
            assert(t.dimension == D);
        }

        //
        // Operators
        //

        Vector& operator=(const Vector& other)
        {
            if (this != &other) {
                _components(other._components);
                dimension = other._components.size();
            }
            return *this;
        }

        T& operator[](const size_t index)
        {
            return _components[index];
        }

        const T& operator[](const size_t index) const
        {
            return _components[index];
        }

    };

    //
    // Operators
    //
    typedef Vector<2> Vector2;
    typedef Vector<3> Vector3;

    template<size_t D, typename T, typename K, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<K>::value>>
    Vector<D, T> operator*(const K& lhs, Vector<D, T>& rhs) {
        Vector<D, T> vec = Vector<D, T>(rhs);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.dimension; ++i)
        {
            vec[i] = vec[i] * lhs;
        }

        return vec;
    }
}
```

I want every arithmetic type (Arithmetic_Type, which has `std::is_arithmetic<T>::value == true`) to have `operator*` work with my custom class. So I tried this `operator*` signature outside of the class.

```
template<size_t D, typename T, typename K, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<K>::value>>
Vector<D, T> operator*(const K& lhs, Vector<D, T>& rhs) {
    Vector<D, T> vec = Vector<D, T>(rhs);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.dimension; ++i)
    {
        vec[i] = vec[i] * lhs;
    }

    return vec;
}
```

It compiles well, but if I try to use them like this, it does not find the `operator*`.
(Since I use Visual Studio, the error code is C2677, "binary 'operator*' : no global operator found which takes type 'Math::Vector<2U, double>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

```
#include "Vector.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    Math::Vector<2> v1 = Math::Vector<2>(2, 3);
    v1 = 2 * v1;
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that matches the error message. There is no `Math` in the code you posted

Comment: For the sake of the question you can replace `Math::Vector` with `std::vector` to purely test your templatization manner.

Comment: @bloody It's not std::vector. It's my own implementation of Mathematical Vector.

Comment: @SangWanJeon While true that doesn’t matter for the question you’ve asked. And while it’s good that you edited the question to include the code, you didn’t respect one of the requirements for a good question: including *minimal* code. The code you’ve included contains a lot of stuff that’s not relevant here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I edited twice, first to include code and second to minimize it. I think you are looking at the first one. Sorry for the inconvenience, but can you reload the question on your side?

Comment: `std::array<T, D> components;
static_assert(components.size() == D, "Component Count must match Dimension");` would assert only if `std::array` (from std) is ill implemented.

Comment: You didn't understand. Replacing it with `std::vector` would make easier for you to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @bloody No, that's not the STL vector... It will make more confusing if I used `std::vector`

Comment: not for the others who might then quicker help you...

Answer (score 0):

You should use this implementation of operator* inside the Vector class:

```
template<typename K>
friend std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<K>::value, Vector> operator*(K lhs, Vector& rhs) {
    Vector vec(rhs);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.dimension; ++i)
    {
        vec[i] = vec[i] * lhs;
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Also, you should fix operator= implementation. You try to change the value of *dimension* field but it is const and you should use operator= to copy the std::array field. So, you can use this code:

```
Vector& operator=(const Vector& other)
{
    if (this != &other) {
        _components = other._components;
    }
    return *this;
}
```